# Using github desktop on windows can't commit changes

Tags: github, npm, commit, husky

**Committing changes fails on github desktop on windows**

Error says:

> warning: Empty last update token.
>
> /bin/bash: C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm: No such file or directory
>
> husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have the latest version of Node.js and npm installed. If not, update them.
2. Check if the file path to npm is correct. If not, update the file path in the github desktop settings.
3. Try running the command "npm install" in the terminal. This might install the missing dependencies.
4. If the above steps don't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling github desktop.